# Convert from seconds to specific format of minutes - Javascript

Tags: javascript

For example:
I have 101.2914
and I want to obtain
1:41.291

I thought to substract the integer part of the number minus 60, but I can't because could be that final time would be 2:XX.XXX

Answer (score 1):

ES6:

```
const string = '101.2914';
let [sec, milisec] = string.split('.');
sec = +sec;
milisec = milisec.slice(0, 3);

let mins = 0;
while(sec >= 60) {
    mins += 1;
    sec -= 60;
}

const result = `${mins}:${sec}.${milisec}`;

console.log(result);
```

Old version:

```
var string = '101.2914';
var array = string.split('.');
var sec = +array[0];
var milisec = array[1].slice(0, 3);

var mins = 0;
while(sec >= 60) {
    mins += 1;
    sec -= 60;
}

var result = mins + ':' + sec + '.' + milisec;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `let min = parseInt(sec / 60); sec = sec % 60;`

Comment: Yes, or just `let min = ~~(sec / 60); sec = sec % 60;` (assuming sec is always positive, which for time makes sense), otherwise the bitwise operator might give wrong result (for negative value).

Answer (score 0):

Yo Can use a function like this as well. Here i am setting input inside the function but you can pass it while calling function.

```
$scope.secToMinute= function (input) {
    input = 101.2914;

    var min = Math.floor(input/ 60);
    var second = input - (min * 60);
    alert(min + ":" + second.toFixed(3));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> I hope this may help you.

```
var seconds = '101.2914';
var date = new Date(0,0,0);
date.setSeconds(seconds);
var result = date.getMinutes() +':'+date.getSeconds()+'.'+seconds.split('.')[1].slice(0,3);
```